# maximum size of file attachments in rich text fields

Tags: rich-text, attachments, multiline-text-field

When a custom list has a multi line text column which allows rich text, users have the possibility to add files to this rich text field (not as an attachment to the list item, but as attachments to this rich text box).

I'm looking for (official if possible) informations, if this files are saved differently then the list item attachments and if there are recommendations regarding the maximum size of this kind of attachments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I didn't see this before, but SharePoint saves those attachments (in the rich text field) to another library (by default on my system: SiteAssets). It creates a folder path in this library, containing the name of the list with the rich text field. Then it stores the file there and creates only a link in the rich text field.

So quota / maximum size will be the under the same restrictions as regular files in a document library.

BUT: If files with the same name are uploaded (in the rich text field) for two or more items in the same list, the second file will overwrite the first in die library, then both items will link to the second file ...